# Python Selenium Firefox popup

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Как заблокировать это уведомление на скриншоте.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/geckdriver')
driver.get("https://test.ru")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver10)
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())

alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

возвращает пустой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

оказалось всё просто

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```